# g++ Compilation option priority

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

when i build, using this line:

```
g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -static *.cpp
```

And my script had some other options like:

```
#pragma GCC optimize("O3")
#pragma comment(linker, ”/STACK:36777216“)
__attribute__((optimize("O3"))) void my_func()
{some code}
```

what will happen ? which one will be kept ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes or pragmas inside file take priority - so if you mark function with

```
__attribute__((optimize("O3")))
```

it will be compiled as if you compile it with -O3 regardless what you passed to gcc e.g. -O0.